# Localization of Wannier functions and periodicity of Bloch states

Tags: condensed-matter

In "Modern Condensed Matter Physics" by Girvin and Yang, the following equation (13.110) relates Wannier functions ($|\chi_{nj}\rangle$, which is localized at site $\boldsymbol{R}_j$) to Bloch states ($|\Psi_{n\boldsymbol{q}}\rangle$)
$$|\Psi_{n\boldsymbol{q}}\rangle=\frac{1}{\sqrt N}\sum_j e^{i \boldsymbol{q}\cdot \boldsymbol{R}_j}|\chi_{nj}\rangle.$$

Then they make the following statement, which my question is about. "Exponential localization guarantees the absolute convergence of the summation over $j$. This immediately implies $|\Psi_{n\boldsymbol{q}}\rangle=|\Psi_{n\boldsymbol{q}+\boldsymbol{G}}\rangle$." Here $\boldsymbol{G}$ is a reciprocal lattice vector.

Can you help see what absolute convergence has to do with the periodicity in $\boldsymbol{q}$? The text seems to imply that it should be obvious, but it's not obvious to me.

Comment: I think that the comment intends only to say that the sum of the series makes sense and thus the left hand side is well defined. Now computing it in $q+G$ we have the stated invariance property since the exponentials in the  right hand side are invariant under that change (I assume that $G$ belongs to the reciprocal lattice).